# Is there an API for Microsoft Teams to see whether a user has logged in?

Tags: microsoft-teams

We're moving over to Microsoft Teams and we want to find people in the company who haven't logged in yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the report of the users activity on teams in the admin panel (see the image attached). Currently we do not have an API version of it. We are working on it but we do not have an ETA to share.
[image]